# Как задать каталог установки в spec-файле для rpm?

Tags: rpm

Здравствуйте!

Как задать каталог установки в spec-файле для rpm-пакета?
В поисковике так и не нашёл ответа на свой с виду простой вопрос, найденные варианты не работают.

У меня есть уже готовые собранные файлы без каких-либо исходников. Они лежат в папке */home/MyProg/build*.
Мне необходимо собрать их в пакет. При этом, чтобы при установке этого пакета эти файлы помещались в папку */opt/MyProgram*.

При таком spec-файле пакет ставит файлы по такому же пути, из которого он их брал при сборке.

```
Summary: MyProg
Name: MyProg
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GPL
Group: MyProg

%description
My PROGRAM!!!

%files
/home/MyProg/build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш `.spec` должен содержать секцию с инструкциями для установки файлов.

Приведу один пример сразу для нескольких типов устанавливаемых файлов:

```
%files
/home/MyProg/build/bin/MyProg       # исполняемый файл приложения
/home/MyProg/build/lib/libMyLib.so* # разделяемая библиотека
/home/MyProg/build/etc/MyProg.conf  # файл настроек приложения

%install
# здесь необходимо указать инструкции для установки файлов (shell-скрипт):
# например:
# для удобства определим переменную:
INSTALL_PATH="/opt/MyProgram"

# теперь создаём директории установки:
mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH/bin
mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH/lib
mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH/etc

# устанавливаем приложение:
install /home/MyProg/build/bin/MyProg $INSTALL_PATH/bin/MyProg
# устанавливаем библиотеку:
find /home/MyProg/build/lib -type f -name "libMyLib.so*" -exec install {} $INSTALL_PATH/lib/{} \;
find /home/MyProg/build/lib -type l -name "libMyLib.so*" -exec cp --no-dereference {} $INSTALL_PATH/lib/{} \;
# устанавливаем конфиг:
install /home/MyProg/build/etc/MyProg.conf $INSTALL_PATH/etc/MyProg.conf

%post
# в этой секции могут содержаться команды, которые будут выполнены после установки файлов
# например, зададим права установленным файлам:
chown -R user:user /opt/MyProgram
chmod 777 /opt/MyProgram/bin/MyProg
chmod 777 /opt/MyProgram/lib/libMyLib.so*
chmod 644 /opt/MyProgram/etc/MyProg.conf
```